# Error en urls django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Mi fichero **urls.py**:

```
#home/urls.py
from django.urls import path, re_path
from home.views import homePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('',homePageView.as_view(),name='home'),
    re_path('activate/(?P<code_>[a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/(?P<email_>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$', homePageView.activate, name='activate')
]
```

Método activate en **views.py**:

```
class homePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    def activate(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            email_ = kwargs['email_']
            code_ = kwargs['code_']
            user = Usuario.objects.get(email=email_,activated_code=code_)
            code = user.activated_code
            if (not user.activated) and code == code_:
                user.activated = True
                user.save()
                messages.success(request, 'User activated successfully')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'Error activating user, please, use the contact form to contact us')
        except Usuario.DoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request,'Error activating user, please, use the contact form to contact us')
        return redirect('home')
```

al entrar en una url como esta:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/activate/aE8w3fqEsoLMykQ/email@gmail.com/
```

me lanza el siguiente error:

> activate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenía que utilizar el método así:

```
def activate(request, *args, **kwargs):
```